# Is there a way to display the key pressed in a TMUX status bar?

Tags: tmux

I will use `tmux` to perform some demo for a video podcast.

I there a way to display the key pressed (both single keystroke, and combinations including modifier keys) in the tmux status bar?

As of now, I'm using [KeyMon](https://packages.debian.org/sid/key-mon) for that purpose. But obviously, it works only from the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the look at the implementation of this plugin [tmux-keylogger](https://github.com/concise/tmux-keylogger). It looks like what you are searching for